# Mutual Toggle buttons - Using two toggle buttons to represent tri-state using triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, togglebutton

I need two toggle buttons to reset each other. Similar to radio buttons but with tri-state. i.e.

- Button 1 is checked
- Button 2 is checked
- None is checked

I tried the following:

```
    <ToggleButton x:Name="Button1" IsEnabled="{Binding IsConnected}">
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource DetailedSettingsButtonStyle}" >
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button2, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>

    <ToggleButton x:Name="Button2"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding IsConnected}">
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource DetailedSettingsButtonStyle}" >
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
```

The result is when Button 1 is checked and I click button 2, button 1 gets unchecked as expected, but button 2 stays unchecked, until I press it again.

So in order to toggle between button 1 and 2, I have to click twice on button 2.

In other words, considering the three states I am trying to create, I have to always pass through the state of non-is-selected everytime, and no way to directly move between the other two states.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `Storyboards`:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="Button1" IsEnabled="{Binding IsConnected}">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource DetailedSettingsButtonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Button2}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>

<ToggleButton x:Name="Button2" IsEnabled="{Binding IsConnected}">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource DetailedSettingsButtonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Button1}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: Any known reason why my original code wouldn't work? Are there tools in VS to debug how the events happens in XAML? Uncover the mysterious creepy world of Microsoft WPF interactions that are not in C#?

Comment: @Bishoy: Basically because that when a trigger's condition stops being true, it tries to undo what it previously did.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the data-trigger for other case as well (Value=False, Set IsChecked=True) for both.

```
<DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
</DataTrigger>
```

But you will lose tri-state behavior. Better to create converters and bind them to a view-model property.

Comment: I'd use radio button in that case